# SPFX Trigger onPropertyPaneFieldChanged after entering value in textbox

Tags: spfx

Presently onPropertyPaneFieldChanged is triggered as you type in textbox. Is there way I can trigger onPropertyPaneFiled only after done entering data in textbox.
Thanks for any help.